# How to set a button as default in ionic alert

Tags: ionic-framework

Normally the last button added in the buttons array is the default/main button which is 'clicked' when enter is pressed inside an input. I want to manually select the default/main button, how can I do this (without changing the order inside the buttons array)? Is there for example a role which I can set to the button?

An example can be found here https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/#alert-inputs

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify existing implementation of `ionic-alert` component in `node_module` folder

```
hello-world\node_modules\ionic-angular\components\alert\alert-component.js
```

Change Line Number 126 with this
**var button = this.d.buttons[0];**

**Note:**

After changing this line close ionic local server and run it again

Answer (score 0):

I know you can use the role cancel for example on the Buttons array

```
{
    text:"Cancel",
    role:"cancel"
 }
```

And with that you dont need the handler function. Thats the only role that i remember from the documentation.